# Gradually dim on smart bulb

Tags: shortcut, homekit

I have an Nanoleaf Essentials smart bulb and I can configure the brightness percentage from the Home app.

When I go to sleep, I do "hey Siri, turn the light on at 7:30 AM". Having it on at 100% wakes me up quite quickly/harshly. I can also do "hey Siri, turn the light to 50%".

I want to make a shortcut that turns the light on at 5%, and gradually goes up to 100%.

Is this possible please?

Comment: I can't test this, but I can imagine this might work as a loop, from brightness 1 - 50 over some time. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts/apdc11deb2c1/ios

Comment: I was looking for a way to tell Siri things (silently)- is Speak the way to do it?

Comment: You need to decide on your workflow, research how you might do it, then ask us when you get stuck. We can't just keep answering a stream of new questions in comments, sorry.